# Power series, but in p-norms

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, banach-spaces

This might seem a bit left-field, but it came up rather naturally in some work I've been doing recently in machine learning and I can't seem to track down any work along the same lines.  In essence, if you start with a (convergent) power series $f:\mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}_+$ with non-negative weights $a_i$:
$$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i x^i$$
you can construct a "series-like" function $g:\ell^1(\mathbb{N}) \to \mathbb{R}_+$:
$$g(v) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i \|v\|_i^i$$
in terms of the $p$-norms $\|\cdot\|_p$.

This seems reasonably well-behaved ($g(v) \leq f(\|v\|_1)$, and $f=g$ if $n=1$ for example, and I believe $g$ defines an [F-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-space)) but I wonder if this has been studied before?  In addition to any interesting/novel properties (which I am of course interested in), I'm particularly wondering if $g(v)$ acts like $h(\|v\|)$ for some norm $\|\cdot\|$ and function $h$ (such a property would be useful, but not essential, for my particular application).

Sorry if that's a broad question but this is one of those cases where either there isn't much prior work or (more likely) I just don't know the keywords I need to google.

Comment: $\ell^1(\mathbb N)$ is a Banach space. the function $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i\|v\|_i^i=\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i\sum_{j\in \mathbb N}v_j^i$ is analytic because it equals its Taylor series. Thus for example you can look at this paper: https://community.ams.org/journals/proc/1965-016-05/S0002-9939-1965-0184092-2/S0002-9939-1965-0184092-2.pdf

Comment: Thanks Zatrapilla, that paper looks like a good starting point, but I'm not sure I follow your maths.  Are you implicitly assuming that $v$ is a positive-valued sequence?

Comment: Oh sorry, you're right, you would have to restrict to the positive orthant for that to work.